# Create columns which correspond to the number of characters contained in strings of a dataframe column

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe, the first column contains string (eg:'AABCD'). I have to count occurences for each string. Then the results for each count must be stored in column (one column for each character, A,B,C,D).
See below

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to get:

[image]

Remark: Columns A, B, C, D contain the number of characters for each string in each line

I want to create columns A,B,C,D with the number of characters for each string in each line

[image]

Comment: Are the columns A, B, C, D already there or do you have to create them? Also, can the strings whose occurrences you are counting, be more than one letter long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns are already in the dataframe, and the column containing the strings to start really is a column and not the index:

Set up dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"string":["AABCD", "ACCB", "AB", "AC"],
    "A":[float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan")],
    "B":[float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan")],
    "C":[float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan")],
    "D":[float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan")],
})
```

Loop through the columns and `apply` a lambda function to each row.

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    if col_name == "string":
        continue
    df[col_name]=df.apply(lambda row: row["string"].count(col_name), axis=1)
```

Comment: I see you are a new user -- please upvote and/or accept this answer as you deem appropriate :-)